# How to run selenium and behave on a local port?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, localhost, python-behave

At this point I'm very familiar with how to get Selenium and Behave to work together to interact with another website (like typing a phrase into an input box). However, because I have created a fullstack python application that I am able to run on my local port 8000, I would like to have Selenium and Behave interact with my site running on the local port the same as it would with an external website. For instance, if I try to run my application on port 8000 and then run Selenium with the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("localhost:8000/")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div[1]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/input'))

select.select_by_value('1')
```

I am met with a 500 server error in the browser.

I have followed along with [this helpful Medium article](https://medium.com/@hmurari/bdd-cucumber-and-selenium-webdriver-based-test-automation-framework-in-python-ae092a7581d3). But again, it uses an external website.

Is this a case to use java -jar in the command line? I don't see how this would work given I have not written anything in Java.

Thank you all so much for any guidance.

**EDITED TO ADD**

Selenium will now open the page (I accidentally had http before localhost)

Comment: When you have your web app running, can you open a regular browser and see `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` ?

Comment: @PixelEinstein I apologize, that was a typo earlier (shouldn't have http in there woops). The page runs just fine actually on http://localhost:8000/. The strange thing is though, when I try to connect to 127.0.0.0:8000/ it does not load (it just keeps trying to connect with no results). I thought 127.0.0.0 was the same as localhost?

Comment: Localhost is mapped to a range, but `127.0.0.1` is the most common address.

Comment: @PixelEinstein hmm interesting, `127.0.0.1` doesn't work either

Comment: Selenium and behvae have nothing to do with it because they use root urllib functions to connect. Unfortunately we can't get you answer because don't see code and config of your application. To localize the problem I suggest try to connect by Requests python package, for example request.get('localhost:8000') and see output.

Answer (score 0):

My solution on this was setting it towards the local IP. In my case it was:

```
http://127.0.0.1:PORT
```